# Failed to connect to mailserver in wamp

Tags: php, email, ssl, wamp

the error is:-( ! ) Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "ssl:smtp.gmail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in F:\wamp\www\ihbt\signup.php on line 75

Actually i am trying to send activation email but the above error is showing up. i am using wamp.

here is the code

```php
<?php
ini_set("SMTP","ssl:smtp.gmail.com" );
$myem = "my gmail account@gmail.com";
$msg = "almost there..";
if (mail("$email", "Activate your email","$msg", "From: $myem")){
    echo "Email sent";
  }
else
    echo "Email sending failed";
?>
```

Comment: How can you send an email without logging in? And also gmail blocks normal logins. You need to enable less secure apps at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: @Manikiran i am logged in into gmail in my browser and i can't find a place to type my pass in php.ini

Comment: It doesn't work that way pal. You have to login using php, refer to this tutorial http://www.9lessons.info/2011/07/send-mail-using-smtp-and-php.html